# How to perform awkward String to Date conversion?

Tags: string, powershell, date

I have a series of dates stored as strings in the following format:

06/23/20 10:05:59:557

and I need to convert them to dates for comparison purposes.

I tried this:

```
#$ldate2 = [datetime]::ParseExact($theDate,'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:ffff',$null)
```

and

```
$ldate2 = [datetime]::ParseExact($theDate,'MM/dd/yyyy',$null)
```

But both cause the script to error.

Comment: "But both cause the script to error." -- What error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample input in your post has a 2-digit year - for that you'll need the `yy` format specifier rather than `yyyy`:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact($theDate, 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss:fff', $null)
```

---

If you want to convert it to a different format, parse it like above then use `ToString()` or `Get-Date -Format` to produce the target representation:

```
$datetime = [datetime]::ParseExact($theDate, 'MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss:fff', $null)

$datetime.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
# or 
Get-Date $datetime -Format MM/dd/yyyy
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think this is the problem. The source has the year format 'yy', whereas date I compare to has the format 'yyyy'. Is it possible to convert between these two types?